# HighStock: One navigator to control two xAxis?

Tags: highcharts

I have created two xAxis one at top and another at bottom (with opposite: true) in my highstock chart. But the problem is that navigator is controlling only the bottom xAxis. Changing the navigator only affects the bottom xAxis not the top one. 
Can we control two xAxis with one navigator in highstock?

Here is my sample code:

```
navigator: {
    xAxis: {
        type: datetime
    }
},

xAxis: [{
    type: datetime,
}, {
    type: datetime,
    opposite: true
}]
```

Comment: Any help/solution on this?

Comment: none of the answers given answer the question, how can the navigator switch between axis, the navigator.setData() function changes the data displayed in the navigator however it still only scrolls the first series

Answer (score 0):

You can catch aftersetExtremes() function http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes and call setExtremes on second axis with defined ranges.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes

Comment: That sounds like a lot of extra work for something that is supposed to be handled automatically by the library by default.

Answer (score 0):

This fairly simple example from the official Highstock demos does it just fine:
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

If it's not working for you, post a minimal version of your code on jsFiddle.